# MySQL Workbench shows results as BLOB

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I keep finding that MySQL Workbench shows query results as `BLOB`. e.g:
`SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449)` --> `BLOB`

If I select to 'view value' I can determine the text value is '10.0.5.9' but it's pretty irritating when I SELECT multiple rows and want to glance at the contents.

Is there a way around this or is it a limitation of the tool?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Background:** 
This problem occurs when the binary string values (BINARY/VARBINARY type) are returned in the results. The binary strings contain the zero bytes and for some reason, apparently security, have not been shown by default. More details about binary strings [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-varbinary.html).

Even in the reported example `SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449)`, the function returns binary string. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) for reference.

**Solution:**
Since MySQL Workbench v5.2.22, it can be set through preferences whether to SHOW or HIDE such values.

1. In MySQL Workbench, go to: *"Edit -> Preferences... -> **SQL Queries**"* OR *"Edit -> Preferences... -> SQL Editor -> **SQL Execution**"* (depending upon what version of Workbench you have).
2. Check the option 'Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string' to show the actual value.

**Reference:**
The original issue has been reported and answered with fix [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53920).

Comment: In Workbench 6.2, the setting is under `Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> SQL Execution`

Comment: Somewhere in the 6.2 range there's a regression: this no longer works.

Answer (score 26):

What you can do is Cast your BLOB type to a string. This will simply allow you to glance at whats in your BLOB type when browsing your select statement.

```sql
SELECT CAST(`blob_column_name` AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 2):

### Another (slightly shorter) solution

```
SELECT CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(myMEDIUMTEXTcol) using utf8) notAblobject FROM myTable;
```

### Unrelated background

My table contains a MEDIUMTEXT column which stores a Base64 string. In my frontend JS code I kept getting an Object returned instead of a string. The Object appeared to contain an array of ASCII values.

Testing the associated query in phpMyAdmin indicated the result was a BLOB. I updated my SQL query, as above, in order to get a simple string returned instead of an Object.