# how to concat two query in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 select concat_ws((
select count(*) from feed_back where schedule_id=1),'/',(select count(*) from event_schedule_mapping where event_schedule_id=1))
as total
```

i am getting  count from both query but when i try to `concat` it using `concat_ws` its give me blobdata as blank please tell me where am doing wrong please suggest.

Comment: https://snag.gy/OFZ8Yu.jpg  in this screen see

Answer (score 0):

Why `concat_ws()` and not `concat()` ?

```
SELECT CONCAT( (First Select),
                '/'
               (Second Select)) as total
```

Comment: same thing i did then also same issue still am getting Blob type data with blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the separator first:

```
    SELECT CONCAT_WS('/', 
        (select count(*) from feed_back where schedule_id=1), 
        (select count(*) from event_schedule_mapping where event_schedule_id=1))
```

[String Functions - MySQL CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
 the right syntax to use
 near 'select count(*) from feed_back where schedule_id=1),'/',
 (select count(*) from ev' at line 1

Comment: try running each query separately, to see the values that returns, look at this [example](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php). Is a simple function, you should not have any problem.

Comment: looking for a bit, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634369/mysql-workbench-shows-results-as-blob), you could try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```html
SELECT sum(a+b) as total FROM (SELECT count(*) as a from feed_back where schedule_id=1) as x, (SELECT count(*) as b FROM event_schedule_mapping where event_schedule_id=1) as y
```