# why does the mySQL workbench always display binary data as being a blob?

Tags: mysql, blob, mysql-workbench

Even if it's storing a single byte of binary data, it shows up as a [blob] icon. I don't understand how 8 bits is a 'binary large object', I was under the impression that blobs take longer to access and should only be used for storing images and media. It's bothering me that the mySQL workbench is treating a 10 character string, which is made up of 10 bytes, like it's nothing, but is calling 8 bits a large object.

Is there a way of storing binary not as a blob, or is it nothing to worry about?
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench shows results as BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634369/mysql-workbench-shows-results-as-blob)

Comment: I'm not sure, from having read it I'm led to the conclusion that this blob icon doesn't actually mean there's a blob in that field, but just serves to hide the binary value for 'security' reasons? It's strange to me that it says blob when it's not actually a blob value though. I just wasn't sure if i had taken the wrong message from it, as the question focuses more on how to remove it than to what the icon implies.

Comment: How would you expect binary data to be shown?

Comment: well the fact that a blob is a binary large object, it implies that there is a different way of storing small binary data. i've heard that blobs are for storing large things like images, but i just want to store like 16 bytes, i wasn't sure if this should be stored in blobs is all