# Decode Base64 column in mysql shows BLOB

Tags: mysql, base64

I'm trying to decode an entire base64 column in MySQL using the from_base64() function but for some reason the result is :
BLOB

How can i decode the column?

**What I tried:**
select from_base64(column);

**What I get:**
BLOB
BLOB
BLOB

[image: Base 64 Decode output (BLOB)]

Comment: you mean binary data? Or literally "BLOB BLOB BLOB"? Well, base64 is used to bring binary data into ASCII format, what did you expect to find?

Comment: Is the content in your BLOB column `'QkxPQiBCTE9CIEJMT0I='`?

Comment: @BillKarwin yes

Comment: @jps yes every cell shows BLOB. The expected result should be a:12, b:14, p:14

Comment: so if the content of the cells is 'QkxPQiBCTE9CIEJMT0I=' then it's decoded correctly to "BLOB BLOB BLOB". Whatever problem you have, it's probably not about decoding, that works fine. Check what you insert into the DB. Seems, something is wrong on that part.

Comment: @jps so im really not familiar with base64. here's an actual example of base64 value within that column : 'eyJhIjo2MywiYyI6Mjk4LCJuIjoxLCJzIjoxLCJlIjo0MCwicCI6NH0='

Comment: @jps  i've added a print screen example

Comment: the data from your comment is `{"a":63,"c":298,"n":1,"s":1,"e":40,"p":4}` . I tried on an [online MySQL fiddle](https://paiza.io/projects/zqUJeRl5riBTtGNRO3_WPg?language=mysql) and it worked fine. I tried with columns of type `text` and `blob`, both with the same result.

Comment: @jps how come I can't see that result in mysql workbench then ?

Comment: You've described two different cases of content, one is `'QkxPQiBCTE9CIEJMT0I='` which is the base-64 encoded version of the string `'BLOB BLOB BLOB'` The other is `'eyJhIjo2MywiYyI6Mjk4LCJuIjoxLCJzIjoxLCJlIjo0MCwicCI6NH0='` which is the base-64 encoded version of the string `'{"a":63,"c":298,"n":1,"s":1,"e":40,"p":4}'` (this looks like the format for a serialized PHP object, no?). I would guess you have at least **two rows in your table** and you're looking at the wrong one.

Comment: @BillKarwin so i mislead you guys sorry. I dont have  'QkxPQiBCTE9CIEJMT0I=' . I though the person asked me if i have values that ressemble this format and that is why i said Yes. How can i decode the base-64 encoded version of '{"a":63,"c":298,"n":1,"s":1,"e":40,"p":4}'

Comment: @RogerSteinberg I understood and I executed exact the same command as you have shown in the screenshot: `select from_base64("eyJhIjo2MywiYyI6Mjk4LCJuIjoxLCJzIjoxLCJlIjo0MCwicCI6NH0=") as decode` and got the result `{"a":63,"c":298,"n":1,"s":1,"e":40,"p":4}` in the fiddle, as mentioned before. So the command should be correct. I have no explanation, why your result is different. You can try it on the fiddle and see the result.

Comment: @jps i see... so you're not sure how to explain the result in my print screen ? I was able to right click on it and open value in viewer where i saw the data under binary, text or json format. is there a way to actually show that instead of having to right click

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't use the same tools. I think the tool expects the result of base64 decoding to be binary and therefore not displayable. Encoding binary data is the most common use case for base64 encoding. Maybe there's a setting to tell the tool to show the result.

Comment: maybe [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634369/mysql-workbench-shows-results-as-blob) helps?

Comment: @jps this solved my issue in viewing the data correctly but how can i separate by columns each key-value pair ?